# trying to read and write to a specific register of ethernet switch using uboot

Tags: ethernet, i2c, u-boot, microchip

I am a new to linux/u-boot and just generally reading and writing to specific registers.

I have a KSZ9897 Ethernet switch, and my goal is to use u-boot i2c commands to set bits [15:13] to 001 to put the switch in the proper test mode.

The following screenshot is of the register that I am trying to read/write to:

[KSZ9897 datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A35DZ.png)

The slave address of this part is 1011_111 = 0x5F

The address of the 16 bit register I am trying to read/write from is [0xN112-0xN113]

The PHY register is 0x09 (I am not sure how this fits in to the picture, but that may be the reason I am having issues)

using u-boot, I am sending the following command:

```
 #i2c md 0x5F 0xN112.2 0x10
```

It reads back the following:

0000: 00 98 97 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4c    ...............L

My suspicion is that this is just reading the first 16 addr values starting at 0x0000. I know this because the 98 and 97 values match up with the default values that should be at address 0x0001 and 0x0002.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here and how I can access register 0x09? I think i am using the proper u-boot syntax, but clearly something is not right here. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The i2c command is wrong, because the third parameter must be a hexadecimal number and N is not hexa, the switch datasheet tells that:

> Address field “N” specifies the portnumber. Valid values for “N” are 1 to 7 for some registers, 6 to 7 for MAC port specific registers, and 0 to 5 for PHYspecific registers.

You should be writing something like this: `i2c md 0x5f 0x1112 1` , the last parameter is the number of bytes you read.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I should have realized that N is not a valid hexa.

Comment: I have another  question now regarding writing to a specific bit. My goal is to write [0 0 1] to bits [15:13] at address 0x1112. I believe i should be using the .2 address modifier correct since this address location is 0xN112-0xN113? To write these bitw what could my command look like? I can only seem to write to the very first bit when i use: 

#i2c mw 0x05f 0x1112.2 0x01 10

It dispays:
1112: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00    ............0...
does this seem right to you for writing to bit 15? and if so, how would i then write to bits 14 and 13?

Comment: Just read out, modify the bits(with bitwise operators) and write back and the last parameter should be 1, because you should write only one register at a time.